# Swap Rows for Columns in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having some trouble trying to change rows by columns.

All I want is change rows and columns of a static 2D array (3x3). I don't want to just simply print the array with reverse indexes. I tried to store the value of the actual position in the array in **int aux** but there is no effect.

Input:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

With this code, the result is the same 2D array. I can't see the problem, can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main ()
{
    int vec[3][3];
    int x, y, aux;
//Input
    for(x=0; x<3;x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<3;y++)
    {
    cout << "POSITION ["<<x+1<<"]["<<y+1<<"]: ";
    cin >> vec[x][y];
    }
}

    cout<<"\nPress ENTER...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    system("CLS");
//Array before the change
cout<<"ARRAY A"<<endl;
for(x=0; x<3;x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<3;y++)
    {
    cout<<vec[x][y]<<"\t";
    }
cout << "\n";
}
//Change
for(x=0; x<3;x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<3;y++)
    {
        if(x!=y)
        {
            aux=vec[x][y];
            vec[x][y]=vec[y][x];
            vec[y][x]=aux;
        }
    }
}

//Array after the change
cout<<"\nARRAY A"<<endl;
for(x=0; x<3;x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<3;y++)
    {
    cout<<vec[x][y]<<"\t";
    }
cout << "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This operation is known as a "Matrix Transpose"; if you search this phrase, you'll find some other discussions which are relevant.

Comment: sounds like an operation for a [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) or [CBLAS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/GSL-CBLAS-Library.html)

Answer (score 4):

You are swapping the elements twice. Hence they come back to their original place.

Change

```
if(x!=y)
```

to

```
if(x < y)
```

So swap only if the element is say (2,3). If it is (3,2), then it is already swapped and we should not swap it again.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is swap.  In the case of a 3x3 matrix, it is just swapping the elements on the lower left and upper right corners:

```
const int SIZE = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
    {
        if (i < j)
        {
            swap(vec[i][j], vec[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we stop `j` from iterating the entire vector.  This is because if we did iterate the entire vector, it would swap them back to their original positions.

Answer (score 1):

As posted below you switch twice. To iterate the fewest amount of times, the smartest change would be to change your second for loop:

```
for (y = 0; y < 3; y++)
```

to

```
for (y = 0; y < x; y++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int N = M-1;  // M is end bound for MxM matrix, only work for Mxm matrix.
int index1 = 1;
for (index0 = 0; index0 < N; index0++) // loop through row
{
    for(index1; index1 < M; index1++) //swapping about the diagn line.   
    {
        tempN = minorMatrix[index0][index1];
        minorMatrix[index0][index1] = minorMatrix[index1][index0];
        minorMatrix[index1][index0] = tempN;
    }
    index1++;  // number of swapping reduce by one after each row.
}
```

Comment: correction, Its MxM and not Mxn, for Mxn matrix, it would requires a more elaborate method.

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping twice mate!
Just swap for `x < y` or `x > y` but not for both.