# Swapping of first column with the first row of [3x3] array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How to swap the first column with the first row of a [3x3] array?
I don't want any changes in the other rows or columns.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574631/swap-rows-for-columns-in-c

Comment: welcome to the site.  Please show your code so far and explain what happens and where you thing the issue is.

Comment: If you did find the solution to your question you should accept the correct answer. So that others can be sure it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
for( i = 1; i < arraySize ; i++){
    int temp = array[0][i];
    array[0][i] = array[i][0]
    array[i][0] = temp;
}
```